# Okhttp3 needs to make unquie properties value like readtimeout for one object

Tags: java, http, okhttp, resttemplate

In okhttp3 the properties value like readtimeout value will be changed for each but the factory object will be singleton.
Does it override the readtimeout value when two thread makes connection at same time

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of OkHttpClient is independent and safe for concurrent use. If you want to share resources between OkHttpClient instances, use `newBuilder()` to make a builder that shares everything with another instance.